# Highlighting text according to text to speech synthesis output

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing windows store app. Going to convert textblock text into speech using speech synthesizer.The requirement is to high light text according to speech synthesis output. I am facing problem while changing text color. just check the following line of code to change color.

**CODE:**

```
    struct SelectionOffsets { internal int Start; internal int End; }
    private void highlightWord(int startIndex, int p)
    {
        try
        {
            var line = txtContent.Text;
            if (p > txtContent.Text.Length)
            {
                p = txtContent.Text.Length;
            }

            SelectionOffsets selectionOffsets;
            TextPointer contentStart = txtContent.ContentStart;
            txtContent.SelectionHighlightColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
            txtContent.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;
            // Find the offset for the starting and ending TextPointers.
            selectionOffsets.Start = startIndex;
            selectionOffsets.End = p;

            txtContent.Select(contentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(selectionOffsets.Start, LogicalDirection.Forward), contentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(selectionOffsets.End, LogicalDirection.Forward));
            var s = txtContent.SelectedText;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

But its not reflecting it on GUI.
I also tried to give trigger for textbox styling.But unable to get  tag in xaml.
Can anyone help me?? Any Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That property just *Gets or sets the brush used to highlight the selected text*... it doesn't select any text. You should use the [`TextBox.Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.select.aspx) to select the text.

Comment: I have used it, I just didn't pasted the code here. I directly came to the point, that applying `selectionHighlightColor` didn't worked.

Comment: It works fine for me, so unless you can provide some code that demonstrates your problem, this question will probably be closed by the community soon.

Comment: And what about if you just call `txtContent.Select(0, txtContent.Text.Length);`?

Answer (score 0):

Selection remains invisible until the ui element is focused.

So try calling txtContent.Focus() after txtContent.Select().

Comment: it gives the same result. and its `txtContent.Focus(FocusState value)`